# Configuring Network without Default Gateway

Tags: network-manager

I'm trying to connect my desktop and laptop using an ethernet connection. I usually configure network from the command line but this time I decided to give Network Manager a try, so I went to Network Connections, and selected manual IP configuration.

At first I left the default gateway field blank, since I don't need a default gateway. Turned out network manager doesn't let me save the connection unless I enter that field, but entering a phony gateway messes up with my Internet connection. Anyway to do this setup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always enter 0.0.0.0 as default GW when I don't really need one.

Actually, if you enter IP and netmask, and never touch the GW field it will automatically fill in 0.0.0.0 as the default GW when you press Save.

Answer (score 1):

It actually does let you save without a gateway.  Try closing the network app manager and restarting it and try again

Comment: No luck. I've tested this on both 11.10 and 12.04 (Alpha 2).

Answer (score 1):

Set up a static IP and type in a phony gateway IP.

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<connection name>` and remove the gateway from the end of the addresses1 line in the IPV4 section.

Before:

```
[ipv4]
method=manual
addresses1=10.1.0.10;24;10.1.0.88;
```

After:

```
[ipv4]
method=manual
addresses1=10.1.0.10;24;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually know how to configure my network interfaces without bothering with NetworkManager at all. I was just wondering if the graphical user interface can do it as well. Apparently not.