# Set specific interface for internet access

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have a machine with three network interfaces running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64-bit, kernel 3.5.0-49.

I am using all three interfaces. Two of them are connected to LANs (eth0 and eth1) and one is connected to the internet (eth2); but when I try to access the internet, it attempts to go through eth0 (error responses come from eth0's IP).

I know that it will work (from experience elsewhere) if I don't set a gateway address for eth0 or eth1, but I have to because for some reason the network manager GUI won't let me save connection settings if no gateway is specified (?).

How do I either a) set eth0 and eth1 to not have gateway addresses, or b) tell the system to use eth2 for internet access (that is, IPs not on eth0/eth1's subnets).

As for trying to unset eth0 and eth1's gateway addresses: Trying to bypass the network manager GUI, I checked in /etc/network/interfaces but Ubuntu doesn't seem to use it (it only has an entry for lo). I'm not really familiar with more modern ways of configuring interfaces though, and so I gave up there.

Comment: In your interface file if you are using network manager should contain only `auto lo`
`iface lo inet loopback ` By default the ethernet uses eht0, can you change your lans use eth1 and eth2?

Comment: @WildMan That's a good idea (moving internet to eth0); I can try it. It's a bit of a hassle to gain physical access to this machine (it's mounted in a ceiling), but I should be able to manage it through the patch bay - although if I mess it up and ruin my remote access (it's headless) I'll need physical access anyways.

Comment: If you have routing capabilities you can check this post out: http://serverfault.com/questions/41077/use-specific-interface-for-outbound-connections-ubuntu-9-04 (it's old, but it's saying to just take out the default gateway and just have one)

Comment: @NoTime Thanks. That's what I was intending to do when I checked /etc/network/interfaces, but since network manager doesn't use it, I can't configure it there. Do you know where network manager keeps the network settings?

Comment: You can manually configure the settings there if you remove network manager or disable it.

Comment: `/etc/NetworkManager`
`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Comment: @NoTime Awesome, thanks. I also found http://askubuntu.com/questions/102339/configuring-network-without-default-gateway at the same time you posted that. I will try that first before I start swapping ethernet cables around.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to set the *default gateway*. You can see the current settings by running `ip route`. You probably want yours to look like something like this:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 ...
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 ...
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 ...
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth2 ...
```

These routes are automatically created by NetworkManager. Try checking **Edit ▸ IPv4 Settings ▸ Routes ▸ Use this connection only for resources on its network** on the two LAN connections to prevent them from becoming the default gateway.

You shouldn't need to work around NetorkManager.

Answer (score 2):

If you for some reason uses NetworkManager but don't have a desktop environment, you can configure it in the command-line:

```
nmcli connection show
```

You should get a list of connections, for example

```
NAME                            UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE  
My Wi-Fi AP                     123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000  wifi       wlp3s0  
Wired connection 1              123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174001  ethernet   enp0s25
```

Then, get the UUID value and execute

```
nmcli connection modify 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174001 ipv4.never-default yes
```

This does the same thing as the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/472743/996767) (may need disconnect and reconnect for changes to apply)

Alternative solutions includes using `route` command to manage default gateway directly; however if you use NetworkManager don't do this (see linked questions on the right pane)