# How to change default interface for internet?

Tags: networking, server, routing

I have a PC with Ubuntu server 18.04 installed on it and I'm trying to use this PC as a server. There are 2 interfaces involved here:

1. To provide Its internet, I am using an android smartphone that has access to internet via its Data and it will be sharing internet with my PC (server) via USB Tethering. This will create an interface called ' enp0s29f7u8 '. This interface will get an IP automatically (DHCP?), mostly '192.168.42.249'.
2. There is another interface called ' enp2s0 ' which is a Huawei internet modem and it's connected to my PC with a LAN cable. This ' enp2s0 ' will serve as an Access-Point so I can SSH to my PC While I'm close. I installed ' ifupdown ' on server so I can assign an Static IP to my Access-Point, namely '192.168.1.10'.

   ```
   $ cat /etc/network/interfaces

   auto enp2s0
   iface enp2s0 inet static 
       address 192.168.1.10
       netmask 255.255.255.0 
       network 192.168.0.0 
       gateway 192.168.1.1
       dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
   ```

Here is the problem: I cannot access internet with this setups. It's like Ubuntu is trying to connect to Internet via 'enp2s0', which is only an AP with no access to internet.

So i tried
`sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down`
and there it is, i have internet. Also, when I do
`sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up`
after that, i still have access to internet.

How can I config my PC so that it will always use 'enp0s29f7u8' to access internet and use 'enp2s0' only as an AP?

**PS:**

1. I really don't understand network stuff. I tried changing default gateway (I don't know why) but it didn't helped(at least the way i did).
2. I'm not a native English speaker. Hope that I could talk my mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set specific interface for internet access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472733/set-specific-interface-for-internet-access?rq=1) ?

Comment: @singrium that is my question exactly. But the answer doesn't fit my situation since my PC doesn't have any desktop environment. Also I tried changing default gateway with `route add change default gw 192.168.42.1` but it didn't work

Comment: Run `ip route` to see which is your default gateway, then run `sudo route delete default gw <IP Address> <Adapter>`. After that, run `sudo route add default gw <IP Address> <Adapter>`. If `route` is not installed, run `sudo apt install net-tools` to install it

Comment: So what is the `enp2s0` interface supposed to be use for?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen it will be an Access-Point so i can SSH to my PC.

Comment: I think you can use the same interface for the internet and the SSH.

Comment: In any case we have the new `netplan` to help out see my answer below` And also please run `cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` and add to your question!

Comment: @singrium that is actually a good idea. i will try it.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i messed the whole OS. currently reinstalling Ubuntu. I will do that when it is done. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set that up via the `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` configuration file. Steps:

1. Edit that file but **make a backup first**:

   - `sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`
   - Add or change the file to this:

     ```
     network:
        version: 2
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
             enp0s29f7u8:
                dhcp4: true
     ```
2. Apply the changes:

   ```
   sudo netplan apply
   # Debug with 
   sudo netplan --debug apply
   ```

Or in your case use `bonding`:

```
bonds:
    bond0:
        dhcp4: yes
        interfaces:
            - enp0s29f7u8
            - enp2s0
        parameters:
            mode: active-backup
            primary: enp0s29f7u8
```

**Note**: Take note of the indentations.

Excerpt:

> Bonding, also called port trunking or link aggregation means combining several network interfaces (NICs) to a single link, providing either high-availability, load-balancing, maximum throughput, or a combination of these. See Wikipedia for details.

Sources:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding?&_ga=2.4304755.1589454052.1542970542-1686101836.1542733354#Descriptions_of_bonding_modes

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan

Comment: i don't know why but after reinstalling OS and having no problem, i faced the same problem again and your answer worked for me. thanks

Comment: Great glad it worked out!

Answer (score 7):

Di you try this:

- To see which is your default gateway, run:`ip route`.
- To delete the current default gateway, run: `sudo route delete default gw
  <IP Address> <Adapter>`.
- To add a new default gateway, run: `sudo route add default gw <IP
  Address> <Adapter>`.

If route is not installed, run: `sudo apt install net-tools` to install it.
**Credits:**
[How to Add or Change the Default Gateway in Linux](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux)

Comment: I had two default routes, and the first was routing to VirtualBox Host-Only network (not suitable to search for Internet). Using the command `route delete` I removed that default route and left the one to LAN router. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**ADVICE**

**This will avoid config manually the default gateway or interface.**

This sometime happen because of the `/etc/network/interfaces` interfaces config order.

- Config this file using priority default order.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to 'use the priority default order'?